# Oracle SQL query, fetching value of occupation in a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

i appreciate your help on this problem :

i have 3 tables (CLIENT,OCCUPATIONS,TRS)

I USE THE FOLLOWING JOINS:

- JOIN cif ON TRS.trs_ac_cif = cif.cif_no
- JOIN OCCUPATIONS ON CIF.OCCUPATION = OCCUPATIONS.OCCUPATION_CODE

AND I NEED TO SELECT COLUMN CALLED BRIEF_DESC IN TABLE OCCUPATIONS WHERE THE CIF_NO = TO_TRS_AC_CIF

But i don't want the where condition to be applied on all of the query, i've trid to do a sub query but error shown 'singe-row subquery returns more than one value'

Thank You,

i've trid to do a sub query but error shown 'singe-row subquery returns more than one value'

Comment: Please, *which* SQL dialect are you *actually* using?

Comment: Please do not tag spam. Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL are totally separate RDBMSs with different syntax and functionality, and clearly you're not using all three at once. Tag spamming (using tags that do not apply to your post) is a quick way to get your question downvoted and/or closed. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should be used properly. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and remove the tags that do not apply, so that we know which RDBMS you're actually using.

Comment: what is "cif" the 3 tables you mention are: CLIENT, OCCUPATIONS, TRS none of those are "cif" also please include the whole query

Comment: The error message "*single-row subquery returns more than one value*" is commonly associated with Microsoft SQL Server, but the title says Oracle and the tags have MySQL, postgresql and Oracle. All 4 options have different syntax to solve this issue - PLEASE choose the correct one (and only one).

Comment: It's also impossible to help you solve the problem without seeing your actual, **complete** SQL statement. Again, reading the [help] pages will improve things for you when posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Although we don't really know enough to be precise, the basic issue is that if you use a ["correlated subquery"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) like the one seen below - that subquery **MUST** return only one value. A very common approach to this is to use MAX() which will force the subquery to produce only one value e.g.:

```
SELECT
      cif.CIF_NO
    , (
        SELECT max(BRIEF_DESC)
        FROM OCCUPATIONS
        WHERE cif.CIF_NO = TO_TRS_AC_CIF -- the "correlation" is here
        ) AS BRIEF_DESC
FROM TRS
JOIN cif ON TRS.trs_ac_cif = cif.cif_no
JOIN OCCUPATIONS ON CIF.OCCUPATION = OCCUPATIONS.OCCUPATION_CODE
```

If you have a more complex need (e.g. you would prefer to have "the most recent" value instead of the maximum value) - then we need the question to provide enough details to enable an answer.